# what is the best way to read US region GCS bucket to write the data into Europe region bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The need is to read GCS bucket(bucket 1) mapped to US region and then write into Europe region GCS bucket(bucket 2).
I would like to find the best solution to achieve the requirement.
I thought to implement bucket-1 as multiregional but I could see below options, not sure how it works If I choose anyone.

[image]

can anyone please suggest the solution.
Note: The requirement is bucket-1 should always be with US region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made it work.
I have created a bucket-1 in US multi regional and bucket-2 in europe-west3 regional.
That's all, my cloud function able to read from bucket-1 and written into bucket-2 successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multi/dual region across continent. So you must have 2 different buckets, not only one.

Then you have to implement solution to replicate data. There is [storage transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service) that offer a convenient way to achieve that, but you don't have a lot of control on the trigger.

You can also implement yourself a copy based on [GCS event and a function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) that simply call a copy API. Not really difficult to implement, but not out-of-the-box